# Arrays and how to update,delete and retrieve an entry

Tags: c#, arrays, console-application

Hi i've got an assignment in which i've had to create a program that holds three arrays one for the persons last name one for the points scored and one for the player number, now i've got all the arrays and things done but i'm confused as to how i'm going to retrieve an entry, update an entry or delete an entry so far the options i've got working are create player, list player and exit the other two i do not know how to do, some guidance in the right direction would really help please and thank you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace PlayerSystem6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //The MAXPLAYERS constant is the physical table size
            const Int32 MAXPLAYERS = 23;

            //Declare the player tables
            Int32[] playerNumbers = new Int32[MAXPLAYERS];
            String[] playerLastNames = new String[MAXPLAYERS];
            Int32[] playerPoints = new Int32[MAXPLAYERS];

            //Keep track of the actual number of players (i.e. logical table size)
            Int32 playerCount = 0;

            //Main Driver
            char menuItem;
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the player system...\n");
            menuItem = GetMenuItem();
            while (menuItem != 'X')
            {
                ProcessMenuItem(menuItem, playerNumbers, playerLastNames, playerPoints, ref playerCount, MAXPLAYERS);
                menuItem = GetMenuItem();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\nThank you, goodbye");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        //Returns either a 'C', 'R', 'U', 'D', 'L', or 'X' to the caller
        static char GetMenuItem()
        {
            char menuItem;
            DisplayMenu();
            menuItem = char.ToUpper(char.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
            while (menuItem != 'C'
                && menuItem != 'L' && menuItem != 'X')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nError - Invalid menu item");
                DisplayMenu();
                menuItem = char.ToUpper(char.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
            }
            return menuItem;
        }

        static void DisplayMenu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nPlease pick an item:");
            Console.WriteLine("C - Create Player");
            Console.WriteLine("R - Retrieve Player");
            Console.WriteLine("U - Update Player");
            Console.WriteLine("D - Delete Player");
            Console.WriteLine("L - List Players");
            Console.WriteLine("X - Exit");
        }

        //Routes to the appropriate process routine based on the user menu choice
        static void ProcessMenuItem(Char menuItem, Int32[] playerNumbers, String[] playerLastNames,
            Int32[] playerPoints, ref Int32 playerCount, Int32 MAXPLAYERS)
        {
            switch (menuItem)
            {
                case 'C':
                    ProcessCreate(playerNumbers, playerLastNames, playerPoints, ref playerCount, MAXPLAYERS);
                    break;
                case 'L':
                    ProcessList(playerNumbers, playerLastNames, playerPoints, playerCount);
                    break;
            }
        }

        //Creates a player in the tables if the array is not already full and the name is not a duplicate
        static void ProcessCreate(Int32[] playerNumbers, String[] playerLastNames,
            Int32[] playerPoints, ref Int32 playerCount, Int32 MAXPLAYERS)
        {
            Int32 number, points;
            String lastName;
            if (playerCount < MAXPLAYERS)
            {
                number = GetPositiveInteger("\nCreate Player: please enter the player's number");
                if (GetPlayerIndex(number, playerNumbers, playerCount) == -1)
                {
                    lastName = GetString("\nCreate Player: please enter the player's last name");
                    points = GetPositiveInteger("\nCreate Player: please enter the player's points");
                    InsertPlayer(number, lastName, points, playerNumbers, playerLastNames, playerPoints, ref playerCount);
                    Console.WriteLine("\nCreate Player: Number - {0}, Name - {1}, Points - {2}, created successfully", number, lastName, points);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("\nCreate Player: the player number already exists");
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("\nCreate Player: the player roster is already full");

        }

        //Inserts the player at the correct location in the tables based on order of 
        //ascending player number. Unless the insert location is at the end, this 
        //requires shifting existing players down in order to make room 
        static void InsertPlayer(Int32 number, String lastName, Int32 points,
            Int32[] playerNumbers, String[] playerLastNames, Int32[] playerPoints,
            ref Int32 playerCount)
        {
            /* PUTS DATA IN NEXT AVALIABLE SLOT
            playerNumbers[playerCount] = number;
            playerLastNames[playerCount] = lastName;
            playerPoints[playerCount] = points;
            playerCount++;
            */

            // PUTS DATA IN PLAYER ASECENDING ORDER
               Int32 insertIndex, shiftCount;
               insertIndex = GetInsertIndex(number, playerNumbers, playerCount);
               for (shiftCount = playerCount; shiftCount > insertIndex; shiftCount--)
               {
                   playerNumbers[shiftCount] = playerNumbers[shiftCount - 1];
                   playerLastNames[shiftCount] = playerLastNames[shiftCount - 1];
                   playerPoints[shiftCount] = playerPoints[shiftCount - 1];
               }
               playerNumbers[insertIndex] = number;
               playerLastNames[insertIndex] = lastName;
               playerPoints[insertIndex] = points;
               playerCount++;

        }
        //Returns the index of the first player number in the table that is greater
        //than the player number to be inserted
        static Int32 GetInsertIndex(Int32 playerNumber, Int32[] playerNumbers,
            Int32 playerCount)
        {
            Int32 index = 0;
            bool found = false;
            while (index < playerCount && found == false)
                if (playerNumbers[index] > playerNumber)
                    found = true;
                else
                    index++;
            return index;
        }

        //Returns the index of the player number in the table 
        //or -1 if the number is not found
        static Int32 GetPlayerIndex(Int32 playerNumber,
            Int32[] playerNumbers, Int32 playerCount)
        {
            Int32 index = 0;
            bool found = false;
            while (index < playerCount && found == false)
                if (playerNumbers[index] == playerNumber)
                    found = true;
                else
                    index++;
            if (found == false)
                index = -1;
            return index;
        }

        //Lists the players in the tables
        static void ProcessList(Int32[] playerNumbers, String[] playerLastNames,
            Int32[] playerPoints, Int32 playerCount)
        {

            if (playerCount > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n{0,7}   {1,-25}{2,6}\n", "Number", "Last Name", "Points");
                for (Int32 player = 0; player < playerCount; player++)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0,7}   {1,-25}{2,6}", playerNumbers[player], playerLastNames[player], playerPoints[player]);
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("\nList Players: the roster is empty");
        }

        //Returns a positive integer
        static Int32 GetPositiveInteger(String prompt)
        {
            Int32 n;
            Console.WriteLine(prompt);
            n = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            while (n < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nError: enter positive value");
                Console.WriteLine(prompt);
                n = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            return n;
        }

        //Returns a non-empty string
        static String GetString(String prompt)
        {
            String returnString;
            Console.WriteLine(prompt);
            returnString = Console.ReadLine();
            while (returnString == "")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nError: must enter keyboard data");
                Console.WriteLine(prompt);
                returnString = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            return returnString;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add or remove values from a C# array. Arrays have a fixed size. That said, you can change the value of any element and you can reassign a new array (minus and element or with an additional element) to the original variable.

```
int[] IDs = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
IDs[2] = 55; // was 3

IDs = new [] { 1, 2, 4, 5, 6 };
```

You might also look at generic lists `List<>()` which can be inserted, updated or deleted from.

Comment: Thanks so within the square brackets of `int[] UDs = new int [] {1,2,3};` would i put what i want changed for example if i want to update one of these playerNumbers, playerLastNames, playerPoints, would it become `int[playerNumbers] IDs = new int[playerNumbers] { 1, 2, 3 };` ?

Comment: I've figured out that i need to create the new processes in a new method like i did with the others but i'm still unsure how i'll be able to use the code you provided and how to implement it in my program, i'm a beginner programmer so i'm unsure.